# Error trying to select standard gestures in Delphi

Tags: delphi, firemonkey, tabcontrol, gesture

I can not select standard gestures in Delphi.  I always get the same error.  Does anybody know why?

---

### Error

### Error reading TGestureStreamData.Control: Access violation at address 500C3A53 in module 'rtl270.bpl'. Read of address 00000008.

### OK

Steps

1. Create a new object
2. add an exit button
3. Add tabcontrol and create some tabItems.
4. Add actionList and create The nexttab and previewstab Action connected with the tabcontrol.
5. Add an gesturemanager
6. I declare the gesturemanager In the  tabcontrol.
7. **Finally** I try to check the left and Right standard Gestures but I get the above error.  No standard Gesture works.

Comment: What steps do we need to take in order to reproduce? Please edit your question.

Comment: The error message indicates that a null pointer is being accessed. That would be a bug in the control's logic.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551) In Delphi, when the error dialog you've posted is shown, you can press Ctrl+C to put an ASCII copy of the error message into the clipboard, which you can then paste into your post here (or into an email or text file for other uses). You can also type error messages into your post if needed. Images should only be used here when the issue cannot be demonstrated in any other way, and plain text can be easily put into your post.

Comment: Ok. I Removed the image.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue, and the only thing that worked for me was:

1. Create a backup of FMX file (just in case you need to turn back and this solution is not working)
2. Delete TGestureManager component if you have it.
3. Open with notepad the FMX file.
4. Delete all references to gestures that you may have in the components. Search for "Touch.InteractiveGestures". Just delete those lines.

Designing interfaces is a bit tedious sometimes in Delphi